# ERROR: chef-server-ctl command not found

Tags: bash, chef-infra

After installation of `chef-server` . 
I run the chef-server-ctl command but I'm getting

```
ERROR: bash: chef-server-ctl: command not found...
```

Comment: What package did you install specifically?

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me once. As coderanger commented above, that error is usually caused by installing the wrong package.

For example:

If you installed the [Chef Client package](https://downloads.chef.io/chef) accidentally instead of the chef server package, you will see `ERROR: bash: chef-server-ctl: command not found...` when running command `chef-server-ctl`

Go to [Chef-server package download page](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-server) and install the correct chef-server package.